# How to open executable files from .so file in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I was going through a project which has program files but their definitions are defined elsewhere,so how to open .so file in linux to check if c++ source files/objects files for the program are present in .so file

Comment: @drescherjn it shows how to list all the .so files but I need to open the files that is made into shared library file

Comment: You cannot recover the original source code from compiled files. The compilation process is a *one way* transformation.

Comment: Will decompiler help in any case?

Comment: Not in reconstructing the original source. That's *impossible*. A decompiler *may* get you some version of a C++ source that can *maybe* get re-compiled to generate something close to what it decompiled, but it'll never look even close to the original.

Answer (score 2):

.so files are shared library files. You can use `nm` to inspect which symbols are defined in the file.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm

Answer (score 0):

The `readelf` can help you. The website is http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html.

You can use `readelf -s ./your-file.so` to see it.